# How do I create collections of sample data in Blend?

Tags: expression-blend, sample-data

Let's say I have a class Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to create some sample data in Blend to help me design my user interface visually.  I choose to create sample data based on a class in Blend, but what I get is a sample Person - singular.  I want to create a collection of Person to bnd to a list box.  How do I tell it to do this?  I can't find anywhere where it asks.  Do I have to create a class that is a collection of Person.  Surely there has to be a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this, though not ideal.

The creation of sample data based on a class is a one-time thing.  Here's what I did to get my list of Person objects in sample data:

```
public class Person
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Age {get; set;}      
}

public class PersonCollection : List<Person> {}
```

I created the PersonCollection class, which is simply a collection of Person objects.  I then created my sample data based on the PersonCollection class - giving me the sample data I was after.  I then removed the PersonCollection, leaving the sample data in place.

I'd call this a workaround rather than a solution.  If anyone can offer a true solution - a way to do this in Blend without having to create summy classes, I'll be more than happy to mark that as the solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a better way to do this?

Comment: If I could give you a million points for this answer I would but I cant so have one instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data pane->Add sample datasource->Define New Sample Data` to do this.

Comment: I want it to be based on my class.  I have a small Person class here to keep it simple, but in reality, I have some complex classes, with deep nested related data, and do not want to define out everything by hand.  I love the ease of using the "Create Sample Data From Class...", I just want it to create a collection of my class, not just a simgular instance.